# Error with click on button: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my jquery script. I have about 100 buttons on my site that change an image on click. After 3-4 clicks I get an error:
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Here's the script:

```
$('body').on('click', '.product_overview .design', function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
        var id = $(this).attr('rel');
        var design = $(this).attr('data');

        $(\".product_overview .designs[rel='\"+id+\"'] .design\").removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');

          $(\".product_overview .prodimg[rel='\"+id+\"'] img\").hide();

          var path = '/overview/'+id+'-'+design+'.jpg';

          var f = $('.product_overview .prodimg[rel=\"'+id+'\"] img').attr('src', path).load(function() {
            $('.product_overview .prodimg[rel=\"'+id+'\"] img').attr('src', f.attr('src'));
            $('.product_overview .prodimg[rel=\"'+id+'\"] img').fadeIn();

        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** I found the error:

```
var f = $('<img />').attr('src', path).load(function() {...
```

did it...